# MSDN licensing for use of SQL Server 2012 and TFS 2013

Tags: sql-server, tfs, licensing, msdn

I have a license for SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition (proc license) and MSDN with VS Pro.  I use TFS 2012 and today on MSDN is TFS 2013, VS 2013, etc.  To install TFS 2013 you have to have SQL Server 2012 SP1 or later.  As a small biz I cannot afford to update to SQL Server 2012 just for TFS's use.  If there was an affordable "upgrade" path from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2012 I would consider it but it looks like it's very expensive, 4 core min at about $8K?

Does anyone know if I can install SQL Server 2012 from MSDN on a server solely for use of TFS 2013?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Developer Edition ($49, or free if you already have MSDN) if this instance is *just* for development / testing / TFS? If it's also the instance you run your production workload on, of course, that's a different story. But if it's just housing your TFS stuff now, you don't need a processor license at all.

Comment: I need the proc license for e-commerce and other database use.  That's why I'm asking about putting SQL 2012 SP1 and TFS 2013 on a separate server solely for TFS via MSDN licensing.

Comment: The problem you're going to have is that this site can't give you legal, licensing or pricing information. We're not lawyers or Microsoft licensing representatives. In fact I'm not even entirely clear if source control falls under development or not, and personally I'm not willing to read the EULA and try to interpret it and give you advice for your situation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about EULAs, licensing and answers would be providing legal advice that would be very difficult for anyone to verify without speaking to the source. I mean, [they have a whitepaper for VS/MSDN licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350). Please contact Microsoft directly.

Comment: Shortcut to always latest version of the Visual Studio, MSDN, and Team Foundation Server licensing whitepaper:  http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/licensing/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL Server (Standard) - so long as it's used only by TFS - is free.  There is a limited use exception in the TFS license.

See my blog for more detail: [MSDN and TFS Licensing Gotchas](http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/10/153981.aspx)

Comment: The latest version of the Licensing Whitepaper (which has this scenario in it as well) is always available at http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/licensing